# How to rsync (or generally "copy") data back from Timeshift snapshot?

Tags: rsync, data-recovery

## Power cut happened, UPS' could not hold

It all started in my little server room, where I needed to shrink one of my client's `ext4` partitions using Gparted on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye), (fully updated):

[image: Gparted shrinking partition - power cut - interrupted]

Then (due to heavy snow, I was later informed) a power cut happened, lasted for hours, my UPS' are not made to withstand such a long time. I have been able to make that image thanks to an unterminated SSH session.

---

## Power has been restored

### Disaster recovery - Step #1

Now, the power has been restored, and what I did so far, was a very long-running `e2fsck`, after which I tried to put the HDD back in her laptop resulting in kernel panic. Expected, but at least I tried.

### Disaster recovery - Step #2

- I did not make any recent full disk image of her computer.
- But I did one timeshift snapshot using the `timeshift-gtk` utility on her Linux Mint 20.2. And with your help, I would like to restore from it.

### Disaster recovery - Step #3 (partial)

Doing the copying, I expect, can't be done with a simple `cp -R`. I am able to mount her main partition on this layout:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM014-SSHD
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C951EEE6-27F7-475C-B000-C23F38B7A190

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1    2048     194559     192512    94M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  194560 1953523711 1953329152 931.4G Linux filesystem
```

Most notably, I was able to obtain her `/etc/timeshift/timeshift.json`:

```
# cat etc/timeshift/timeshift.json

{
  "backup_device_uuid" : "70f3734c-3f99-490e-84bf-382b67a1c6bc",
  "parent_device_uuid" : "",
  "do_first_run" : "false",
  "btrfs_mode" : "false",
  "include_btrfs_home_for_backup" : "false",
  "include_btrfs_home_for_restore" : "false",
  "stop_cron_emails" : "true",
  "btrfs_use_qgroup" : "true",
  "schedule_monthly" : "false",
  "schedule_weekly" : "false",
  "schedule_daily" : "false",
  "schedule_hourly" : "false",
  "schedule_boot" : "false",
  "count_monthly" : "2",
  "count_weekly" : "3",
  "count_daily" : "5",
  "count_hourly" : "6",
  "count_boot" : "5",
  "snapshot_size" : "5819856261",
  "snapshot_count" : "306936",
  "date_format" : "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",
  "exclude" : [
    "+ /root/**",
    "+ /home/ruzena/**"
  ],
  "exclude-apps" : [
  ]
```

- 

The storage unit is:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 7.28 TiB, 8001563221504 bytes, 15628053167 sectors
Disk model: Expansion Desk  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 31C6FA70-A6CD-4EBA-8DD9-D07C90FA677D

Device          Start         End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1        2048  7814158335 7814156288  3.6T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc2  7814158336 15628053133 7813894798  3.6T Linux filesystem
```

- Note, that I have set it up all-inclusive.
- I have 1 (one single) `timeshift` snapshot dated: **2021-12-05**_14-38-56, which she agreed would be a satisfactory date to restore.

---

My head is spinning around right now, can we save her laptop by some `rsync` copy command, please? (I never used it on itself, so my trying would probably cost more time than asking you.)

I will be waiting for 2 hours from now for a response, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What I actually did - Not a direct answer

I did think about it a lot during those 2 hours. And the result surprised me, I *scanned* the `timeshift` snapshot `/home` for all sorts of files, not really many there at all. This gave me an opportunity to do a clean installation. It took me many hours, but at the end of the day, I think it is for the best.

### Feel free to add an *actual* answer

And if making any sense, I will accept it.

### Special thanks

Going to [vfbsilva](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/44398/vfbsilva) for commenting correctly, let me quote before it disappears:

> Timeshift works on differentials I'm not sure of how messed is it. But before any more changes have you mounted it with another disk and saved relevant data she might have in the home partition?